# How to use htaccess to do a permanent redirect with status code 301?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have the following code in my htaccess :

`RewriteRule ^test.html$ index.php?ctrl=location&action=view [L]`

The problem is that my page is accessible by 2 addresses :

- ./index.php?ctrl=location&action=view
- ./test.html

And I would like that, when I type `http://website.com/index.php?ctrl=location&action=view` in the url, it does a 301 redirection to `http://website.com/test.html`.

I tried the following but it does the contrary :

```
RewriteRule ^test.html$ index.php?ctrl=location&action=view [R=301,L]
```

And I tried other things but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect from old url to the new one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?ctrl=location&action=view [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /test.html? [L,R=301]
# map new url to the old location
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /index.php?ctrl=location&action=view [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't change anything. Maybe my problem is because of slash at the begining of path ?

Comment: @Cainzer So you are trying `https://example.com/index.php? ctrl=location&action=view` but nothing is happening? No url redirection and the url stays same?

Comment: Yes the url stays the same